# problem with connecting with the serial port in php

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, serial-port

I'm trying to send/receive data from my PC to the serial port with the "PhpSerial.php" library. the code works fine when I run it with php CLI `php -f test.php`. but when I load the php file from the browser it doesn't work and prompts this warning "Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in /opt/lampp/htdocs/examples/PhpSerial.php on line 120".

so How to solve this problem?

I use ubuntu 20.04 and xampp 8.1.2.

```
 <?php
include "PhpSerial.php";

// Let's start the class
$serial = new PhpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");

// We can change the baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");


// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

sleep(3);

// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("1");

$serial->deviceClose();
?>
```

The user is added to dailout group.

Comment: No, it's running on my pc

Comment: I want to control the Arduino connected to the USB port from a web page on the same pc.